# Fastest way to search an array on m1 mac

Tags: assembly, apple-m1, simd, arm64, neon

I am trying to load an array of u16s from memory and find the first element that is less than some number, as fast as possible on an M1 mac. I have been looking through the NEON instructions, but I wasn't able to find a good way to do it. There are comparison vector instructions, but they leave you with vectors of elements of all 1 or 0. How would you get that into a general purpose register? And is there a way to break a loop by testing a vector instruction?

Comment: Have a look at how memchr is implemented in hand-written asm (e.g. in glibc (GPLed, but see https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/aarch64/memchr.S.html) or Apple's libc for macos); perhaps with scalar, perhaps with vector byte-compare and `sri` (shift-right and insert) or `umaxp` (unsigned max, pairwise) to narrow to 64-bit + move to scalar for a compare (and `rbit`/`clz` if non-zero).  You could do the same thing for u16 elements.

Comment: How long is the array typically/min/max?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE It would be between 0 and 10.000 elements

Comment: You can use neon for this. but you shouldn't expect an enormous performance boost since neon to arm register transfer causes a total pipeline stall of fifteen cycles. I suggest to deal with 128 data per iteration, shrink the booleans to 128bits, transfer the 128 bits boolean to two 64bit register, then `clz` as Peter suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// int32_t searchArrayU16(uint16_t *pArray, uint16_t threshold, uint32_t len);
// assert(len & 127 == 0);
// assert(len >= 128);

    .arch armv8-a
    .global searchArrayU16
    .text


pArray0 .req    x0
thresh  .req    w1
len     .req    x2
stride  .req    x3
pArray1 .req    x4
count   .req    w5
val0    .req    x6
val0w   .req    w6
val1    .req    x7
val1w   .req    w7

.balign 64
.func
searchArrayU16:
    adr     x15, 2f
    dup     v0.8h, thresh
    ld1r    {v1.2d}, [x15]
    mov     stride, #128
    add     pArray1, pArray0, #64
    mov     count, #0

    b       1f

.balign 8
2:
.byte   1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128

.balign 64
1:
    ld1     {v16.8h-v19.8h}, [pArray0], stride
    ld1     {v20.8h-v23.8h}, [pArray1], stride
    ld1     {v24.8h-v27.8h}, [pArray0], stride
    ld1     {v28.8h-v31.8h}, [pArray1], stride

    cmhi    v16.8h, v0.8h, v16.8h
    cmhi    v17.8h, v0.8h, v17.8h
    cmhi    v18.8h, v0.8h, v18.8h
    cmhi    v19.8h, v0.8h, v19.8h
    cmhi    v20.8h, v0.8h, v20.8h
    cmhi    v21.8h, v0.8h, v21.8h
    cmhi    v22.8h, v0.8h, v22.8h
    cmhi    v23.8h, v0.8h, v23.8h
    cmhi    v24.8h, v0.8h, v24.8h
    cmhi    v25.8h, v0.8h, v25.8h
    cmhi    v26.8h, v0.8h, v26.8h
    cmhi    v27.8h, v0.8h, v27.8h
    cmhi    v28.8h, v0.8h, v28.8h
    cmhi    v29.8h, v0.8h, v29.8h
    cmhi    v30.8h, v0.8h, v30.8h
    cmhi    v31.8h, v0.8h, v31.8h

    uzp1    v16.16b, v16.16b, v17.16b
    uzp1    v18.16b, v18.16b, v19.16b
    uzp1    v20.16b, v20.16b, v21.16b
    uzp1    v22.16b, v22.16b, v23.16b
    uzp1    v24.16b, v24.16b, v25.16b
    uzp1    v26.16b, v26.16b, v27.16b
    uzp1    v28.16b, v28.16b, v29.16b
    uzp1    v30.16b, v30.16b, v31.16b

    and     v16.16b, v16.16b, v1.16b
    and     v18.16b, v18.16b, v1.16b
    and     v20.16b, v20.16b, v1.16b
    and     v22.16b, v22.16b, v1.16b
    and     v24.16b, v24.16b, v1.16b
    and     v26.16b, v26.16b, v1.16b
    and     v28.16b, v28.16b, v1.16b
    and     v30.16b, v30.16b, v1.16b

    addp    v16.16b, v16.16b, v18.16b
    addp    v20.16b, v20.16b, v22.16b
    addp    v24.16b, v24.16b, v26.16b
    addp    v28.16b, v28.16b, v30.16b

    addp    v16.16b, v16.16b, v20.16b
    addp    v24.16b, v24.16b, v28.16b

    add     count, count, #128
    addp    v16.16b, v16.16b, v24.16b

// total pipeline stall here

    mov     val0, v16.d[0]
    mov     val1, v16.d[1]

    orr     x15, val0, val1
    cbnz    x15, 1f // found a match!!!

    cmp     len, count, uxtw
    b.hi    1b
.balign 16
    mov     w0, #-1     // no match found
    ret

.balign 16
1:
    rbit    val0, val0
    rbit    val1, val1
    cmp     val0, #0
    sub     w0, count, #128
    sub     w1, count, #64
    clz     val0, val0
    clz     val1, val1
    add     w0, w0, val0w
    add     w1, w1, val1w
    csel    w0, w0, w1, ne
    ret
.endfunc
.end
```

Here you are. It returns -1 when no match is found.
It should work on all `armv8-a` cores or above.

Comment: `and     v16.16b, v16.16b, v1.16b` is a no-op, right?  I think that got left over from copy/pasting to AND all the other pairs with `v16`.  (Why?)     Also, what's the point of putting `.byte   1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128` in the middle of the function where you have to jump over it, instead of in `.rodata` or something?

Comment: `cmn val0, val1` could produce `0` when both inputs are non-zero, for example `-1 + 1` or `0x8000... + 0x8000....`.  If you're trying to set flags according to any of 128 bits being non-zero, `orr x1, val0, val1` / `cbnz x0, 1f` works in all cases, unlike a reversible function such as addition.  (It seems that `orrs` to OR and set flags isn't available in AArch64? But `cbz` instead of branching on flags works, at the cost of a temp register, like thresh which we're done with.)

Comment: What's the point of `.balign 16` before a `ret`?  Nothing branches to that `ret`, so putting some NOPs before a `ret` is just going to make them get fetched and decoded.  Does branch prediction not like it when there are too many branches within the same 16-byte chunk or something?  Is that a known optimization for Apple M1, the microarchitecture the OP is optimizing for?  Are you sure it specifically stalls on `mov` from SIMD to integer?

Comment: @PeterCordes 1) What's wrong with `v16`???? I like to start the loop aligned to 64 bytes (i-cache and branch preditcor), and since pre loop code is less than 16 instructions long, it's the perfect place for literals.

Comment: @PeterCordes 2) You are right. Even if the chance is less than one to four billion square, it's not zero. I'll correct the code correspondingly.

Comment: @PeterCordes 3) During the decode phase, the cache controller, branch predictor, and `cpsr` is triggered if an instruction being decoded needs any of them. It's advisable not to put those instructions within the 16bytes boundary with the loop ending branch. And correct me if I'm wrong: I consider `ret` a branch instruction.

Comment: Oh, I misread `and     v16.16b, v16.16b, v1.16b` as having all three operands being `v16`, but actually the last operand is `v1`.  Re: mixing code and data: that means that line and page have to be hot in both L1d and L1i caches, and iTLB + dTLB.  There's presumably no other data on the page, since I don't think AArch64 compilers use literal pools between functions like they do for ARM32.  Does aligning the top of the loop by 64 vs. 32 give a speedup on M1?  (If the OP uses this code in a MacOS application, it's unlikely to run on other microarchitectures any time soon, unlike with Android.)

Comment: Yes, `ret` is a branch instruction that needs branch prediction.  Despite having a special predictor for return instructions (typically a stack of recent call addresses), it does normally count for branch-prediction throughput / density limits.  e.g. AMD K10 had an issue with x86 `ret` being within one byte of a jump destination or fall-through, hence `rep ret` to pad it to 2 bytes.  I don't know if Apple M1 has a limitation here.  Even if so, does decode stall for just an extra cycle?  And putting the `ret` in a different 16-byte block would also make it decode a cycle later?

Comment: @PeterCordes They never reveal how exactly their branch predictor works, hence I don't know if the 64 bytes alignment brings much. But I'm sure it's beneficial for i-cache, and it doesn't hurt. Honestly, it doesn't matter at all if the code takes 1 or two cycles more **outside the loop**, and ARM needs more literal pool in code area than x86 anyway.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's all about power consumption on ARM. We should avoid triggering any special component unnecesarrily.

Comment: Some people have worked on reverse-engineering M1 cores; https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WrMYCZMnhsGP4o3H33ioAUKL_bjuJSPt/view is a copy of it.  Unfortunately it's not easily searchable or indexed, nothing like Agner Fog's x86 guides; it's as much about the details of their reverse-engineering methodology as their actual results.  So I wasn't able to find if they'd tested branch density bottlenecks.

Comment: @PeterCordes 110 entry loop buffer? OMG...... I read a study that the Cortex-A15's power conumption is reduced by 27% when its loop buffer(32 entry) kicks in. I was so furious when when one of my routines had a loop consisting of 33 instructions, and there was absolutely no way to reduce that number.